# How do I sign Facebook's Technology Provider Amendment as requested by Facebook's App verification process?

Tags: facebook

I'm trying to request our Facebook app be reviewed in order to add permissions to it however it will not let me until our business has been verified.

I have successfully verified our business, but signing the 'Tech Provider Amendment' is still unchecked in our Apps settings. Where can I find this document in order to sign it?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/?translation#tech-provider-amendment: _“If you are a business that will use our APIs and data to serve other businesses, during Business Verification you will be asked to provide an email address for a Tech Provider Signatory. We will email the signatory a link to our Tech Provider Amendment, […]”_ - did you not get asked for an e-mail address for this purpose during business verification?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @misorude, i've just gone through the verification process again with a mock business. Unless they ask for the Tech Provider Signatory after the business has been reviewed, they have not asked for a Tech Provider Signatory email yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution: Sent app to review, after the app is verified successfully the tech provider amendment is sent to you via e-mail

The tech provider amendment (as documented here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/?translation#tech-provider-amendment) is not being sent during the business verification process. Saidly this is just wrong!

Have a look at our conversation with FB here, that should make everything clear: https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/1382063485295412/

Comment: Thanks for your answer swervedriver. On a side note: have you had any luck getting your 'Page Public Content Access' permission request approved for your social wall? We have applied using the same use case and have been rejected.

Comment: Currently our app is in review, I will keep you informed!

Comment: Cheers, best of luck!

Comment: Any luck getting those permissions? @swervedriver